# How to set Histogram JFreeChart YAxis maximum value?

Tags: java, jfreechart

This is my first question, so maybe it is a silly one.
I have a histogram to compute a grayscale image pixel values. Something like this:

```
HistogramDataset dataset = new HistogramDataset();
dataset.setType(HistogramType.FREQUENCY);
dataset.addSeries("", values, 256, 0.0, 256.0);
```

But the histogram doesn't show as I expect, because my values are from 0 to 22400  and how does the histogram know which bean has which value? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the [`addSeries()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html#addSeries%28java.lang.Comparable,%20double%5B%5D,%20int,%20double,%20double%29) link, which shows the corresponding [source code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/statistics/HistogramDataset.html#line.141), to see how your `values` are apportioned among the requested number of `bins` in `binList`.